# message format in rails3

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, text-formatting

i want to save my text message in same format as it is typed ans display it in the same format.

Suppose i type:

```
Hi,
   How r u? how is your daddy?

 Thanks & regards
 Your friend
```

but it will dispalyed as

```
Hi, How r u? how is your daddy? Thanks & Regards Your friend
```

in my view file i have something like this:

```
<table class="display stylized" id="act_details">
       <thead>
          <tr>
                 <th>Message Details</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody> 
               <!--<tr>
                  <td colspan="2">Message from <strong><%= @message.from %></strong></td>
               </tr>-->
               <tr>
                 <td colspan="2"><label>Subject:</label> <%= @message.subject %></td>
               </tr>
              <!-- <tr>
                 <td colspan="2" wrap><label>Message:</label> <%= word_wrap(@message.description, :line_width => 80 ) %></td>
               </tr>-->
                <% @replies.each do |reply|%>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan ="2" wrap><label> Sent by <%= reply.from.capitalize %> on <%= reply.created_at %> </label> <br/><%= word_wrap(reply.description, :line_width => 80)%></td>
                  </tr>
                <%end%>
        </tbody>      
</table>
```

I am using rails 3.0.6. Is their any way to show the message as it is typed, i am sure their is something as i want but unable to get those. Any help will be thankful.

Comment: Are you trying to show this in your view? Can you add the code for the part of the view where you try to display this?

Comment: yes @dpassage you are right i want to display it in my view, i have edited my question please have a look.

Comment: OK, this is really more of an HTML question, then. This will just grab the bytes from your object, escape the html characters in it, and then render it out. You could try using <pre> around it.

Comment: Hi @dpassage I have found a solution just check my answer, it is same as i want.Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Oh! So it does. Nice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello friends i have got a solution. Rails has a built in method "[simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format)"

And it is so simple to use and works well. Thanks a lot to this.